# Mongosh while loop throwing Missing semicolon error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, while-loop, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I have a js file that runs the mongo shell commands, it was working fine until introducing while loop in the file. Here is the code:

```
let id = 2;

while (id <= 15) {

    // Use the Database
    if (id == 2) {
        use test1
    } else if (id == 3) {
        use test2
    } else {
        use test3
    }

    // further operations

    id++;
}
```

The Error is:

```
> Uncaught: SyntaxError: Missing semicolon.
>      use test1;
>         ^

> Uncaught: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)
> }
> ^
```

Thanks in advance!